# How to prevent CSRF attacks?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, csrf

I want to prevent CSRF attacks on my API (Express app nodejs)
I searched google and youtube but I can't find way to do it. On the youtube tutorial it said generate a token and send it to the client side but won't the hacker just send a request to get csrf token and bypass the csrf thingy? I'm confused please help.

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we work on the policy that the user must show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **traditional** CSRF attack works by placing a pre-populated form on the the attacker's site and submitting it cross-origin. It then uses credentials that are automatically sent with the request to send the attacker's data under the guise of the browser owner's identity.

By putting a token in both the cookies (or session) and the form and checking to see if they match, you can defend against this. The attacker can't just send a request to get the CSRF token because:

- If they get the user to make the request then the Same Origin Policy prevents them from reading the response with the token in it
- If they make the request directly then they won't have the user's cookies so will get a different (non-matching) token

---

When you are dealing with a **web service** (and you need to make that API work across origins), things are different. The key defence here is to design the API so either:

- The credentials go somewhere where they won't be sent automatically (e.g. in an Authorization header) so the attacker can't make the request with them.
- The request is in a format where it requires a CORS preflight request to send (e.g. with a `Content-Type: application/json` request header).

… or both.

Comment: yeah well, the internet evolves...
"It then uses credentials that are automatically sent", not really, nowadays cookies are SameSite=Lax by default, 
also, nowadays browsers send a (forbidden header name, cannot be changed with javascript) "Origin: https://myrealsite.com" header, the server simple has to ensure that that value is myrealsite.com and not an attacker.com. No need for csrf token at all:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158045/is-checking-the-referer-and-origin-headers-enough-to-prevent-csrf-provided-that